# VBA Custom NumberFormat

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small macro that applies a custom numberformat to a block of cells:

```
Sub Inches()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "General"" inches"""
    Next r
End Sub
```

So if a cells contains 1.25 it would display as:

1.25 inches

I need to change this macro so that rather than *inches* being displayed, the double-quote character will be displayed instead.

I have not been able to escape the double-quote's functionality.

Comment: This works using single quotes: `r.NumberFormat = "General""'""'"`

Comment: Also `r.NumberFormat = "0.00''"` works. I think key is using two single quotes to create double quote as far as I can tell

Comment: @AlexP - This is spot on! .....Thanks!!

Comment: You can also escape the quotes like this: `activecell.NumberFormat = "general \"""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
r.NumberFormat = "General"" '""'"
```

It's using two single quotes, not a double quote, but it may be an adequate approximation for now.

Answer (score -1):

Try appending CHR(34) to your output string e.g.

NumberOfInches = 4

Debug.Print NumberOfInches & " " & CHR(34)

Comment: That will change the contents of the value to a text string

Comment: @Gary'sStudent If you wanted to use something similar, you could do .NumberFormat = "General\" & Chr(34).